# Reading Email With Java + Cron

Tags: java, email, cron

I can send email through Java quite easily. What I'd really like to do is have a Java program check an email account for new mail, read the contents of the mail and react accordingly. I have no idea where to start with this or what sort of thing to Google for, so I don't really have much to add beyond this - does anyone have any suggestions of libraries or other methods?

Comment: What OS and Mail host are you using? I assume the cron tag is a hint to Linux?

Comment: Yeah, it'll be Linux. The mail host is variable - I'm willing to use any host that'll work with this. GMail, Microsoft Exchange are two that pop to mind.

Comment: Why would you need OS chron, if you have Quartz Scheduler in Spring? (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Google about [quartz triggers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz), [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/). Also I remember we used [Chillcat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-email.asp) library for these purposes, but it's not free.

Comment: Commons Email seems to be mostly about sending email, can it retrieve also?

Comment: Oh wow, that's definitely looking good. Thanks for that. Accepting this answer as Apache Commons stuff has served me well in the past, and I've had issues with JavaMail previously.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with either POP3 or IMAP type libraries to access the account.

Comment: Okay. So the standard JavaMail API maybe?

Comment: As far as how Java interacts with the messages, I'll leave that to you as I have very little experience with that. But the two most common (and commonly accepted) ways of reaching out to check remote mailboxes for new mail are IMAP (preferred) and POP3 (on the road to deprecation). Although the paranoiac in me wants to say use the SSL versions instead (IMAPS, POP3S)...